# Google Code and Eclipse Update Site

Tags: java, eclipse, git, google-code

I am trying to use an Eclipse Update Site project from a Google Code project site (http://code.google.com/p/mdpm).
It uses a git repository, here is the url to the update site
https://code.google.com/p/mdpm/source/browse/#git%2Fcom.lowcoupling.mdpm.updateSite

The problem is that Eclipse doesn't manage to get it from the Install New Software dialog.
I mean I clearly understand the problem is that these urls are not direct and actually returns a web page, not a folder as Eclipse would expect. But, since it seems google has disabled the "downloads" from google code, how should I do that?

Is there any direct URL to my resources?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I can answer my own question
the direct url is http://mdpm.googlecode.com/git/com.lowcoupling.mdpm.updateSite/

Comment: How did you get the direct URL?

Comment: ops, I don't remember actually... but I guess it is always something like http://<projectName>.googleode.com/git/<theResourceYouWantToPointAtInYourProject>

Comment: now I see what you meant! check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166515/google-code-git-url