# Google Code Git URL

Tags: git, google-code

I have two projects on google code

called mdpm and donoproject

This url to the first git repository works http://mdpm.googlecode.com/git/
I cant see why this does not http://donoproject.googlecode.com/git/

Comment: is the mdpm project order than donproject?

Comment: [Edit of above comment] is the mdpm project order than donproject? Believe Google has changed the access for newer projects and that's what's causing the problems (I'm trying to setup an eclipse update site and I'm failing...) possibly https://bintray.com/ could come to the resque...

Comment: mmmh I am migrating to github thank you anyway

Comment: But you can't host an update site on github, right?

Comment: i.e. https://github.com/lowcoupling/dono/raw/master/com.lowcoupling.dono.updatesite